# how to enforce singleton behavior on a timer-triggered function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I want my Azure Function to look at an SFTP folder, and move new files to their parent folders.

My scaffolding looks like this.

```
public static class OnMoveFilesHttpTriggered
{
    [FunctionName("OnMoveFilesHttpTriggered")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

**How do we enforce that there will be one and only one instance of this function running at any given time?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's by design that TimerTrigger uses the [Singleton](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/Listener/TimerListener.cs#L14) feature of the WebJobs SDK to ensure that only a single instance of your triggered function is running at any given time. Hence we don't have to do anything else to enforce it.

Check the [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#singleton-locks) for details.

> When the JobHost starts up, for each of your TimerTrigger functions a blob lease (the Singleton Lock) is taken. This distrubuted lock ensures that only a single instance of your scheduled function is running at any time. If the blob for that function is not currently leased, the function will acquire the lease and start running on schedule immediately. If the blob lease cannot be acquired, it generally means that another instance of that function is running, so the function is not started in the current host.

Comment: thanks so much! we don't even need to decorate it with the `Singleton` attribute??

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' No need indeed, explicit decoration is used for other triggers, singleton mode is built-in for timer trigger.

Comment: so what happens exactly if it the first instance is not done runing yet and the timer goes off, attempting to open a second instance?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Wait for work in first scheduled time to finish and execute in next following schedule. Only one timer trigger instance is on at any time.

Comment: @JerryLiu this `distributed lock` will work across regions? I think that's the idea but just to confirm, because it wasn't my experience

Comment: This is only partially true. If it is running and you manually trigger it, it is possible to have multiple timer triggers running at the same time.

Comment: I have another question: when I run my timer triggered orchestration locally it runs multiple instances. So is the behaviour different from the azure environment?