# Limit number of servers on Azure functions (consumption plan)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to fix a cap on the number of servers on which the azure functions scale? I have a consumption plan and basically I would like to set a cap on the number of resources that azure functions can use.

The only solutions I found are:

- set a cap for daily GB/sec threshold, after which the functions are stopped until the following day, which is definitely something I do not want because I need to use some functions for online tasks.
- In the host.json, changing parameters for `http.maxConcurrentRequests` and `http.maxOutstandingRequests`, which will affect the number of concurrent functions running. Is this the thing should I look into? isn't this setting per-server level? my fear is that this won't end up capping resources, but insted will let Azure create just more and more servers, in order to comply with request loads

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT app setting: The maximum number of instances that the function app can scale out to. Default is no limit.
Note: This setting is a preview feature - and only reliable if set to a value <= 5

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#websitemaxdynamicapplicationscaleout

Comment: Could you confirm that it works with Consumption Plan (as requested in question)? I found some contradictory information about this here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/523

Comment: Newer link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_max_dynamic_application_scale_out and still tagged as preview feature : This setting is a preview feature - and only reliable if set to a value <= 5

Comment: I've run tests and (at least for myself) have proved that for low requests per second, this works for a few minutes of testing then at a higher level of requests per second Azure spins up new servers regardless of that setting. Without that setting servers get spun up almost straight away, i think it's how Azure prevents hotspots by spreading "EVERYTHING" across their network, it's sensible. Sorry that sounds too positive, let me be totally clear ... that setting does not work on consumption plan at all.

Comment: the simplest test to do is to run a mini "load test" against a few endpoints, 100 requests per second was what I used, and then open AppInsights and view "Live Metrics", link in the main menu on left. At the bottom of the screen you'll see a list of the servers. Run the load test and watch the extra servers "pop up" after a few seconds. Remove setting above, re-start and run load test, and you see the new servers appear almost immediately.

Comment: @SimonLuckenuik sorry to downgrade your reply, because it's technically correct according the documentation, but the documentation is wrong. Its not reliable at all, even whe the value is <=5, i.e. 1 in our case.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that [timer-triggered functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=javascript) are automatically singletons. In my case that was sufficient, as I can wake-up such function every minute and process specific amount of data. Even if the function takes longer than expected, there's no risk a second one will be run concurrently.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53919048/4619705